# How to add Nitrotasks to startup applications in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: startup-applications, nitro

Always, when I want to add an application to startup, I use system monitor to find run-command and then add it to startup. But in Nitrotaks case the run-command is "/usr/bin/python/opt/nitro/bin/nitrotasks" and when I add it, doesn’t work. I've checked "nitrotasks" too. What do you suggest me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an application to start-up applications, just type start in Dash, and click on Startup Applications.

[image]

Once you click on it, and the new window opens, click on add to add you desired application.

[image]

A window will open asking for the apps info.  Once you're done filling out all the information, click on Add, and you're done.

[image]

Comment: I did these steps but I don't know what is run-command for Nitro. Can you guide me how to browse an app ?

Comment: The command to run it is: `/usr/bin/nitrotasks`  I just installed nitro tasks, and used the same command, rebooted, and it worked.

Comment: the result is disappointing. 
/usr/bin/nitrotasks: No such file or directory

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: by Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: I've installed it from terminal.  Try it that way, and see.

Comment: I've found my path in "/opt/nitro/bin/nitrotasks" if installed by Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

If you can start it from command line, try `which nitrotasks`. It should show you the install path. Then follow Mitch's steps